# How to create a python script to reduce image size without noticeable quality loss?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I was using PIL to resize an image to 144x72 size. However, the resized image appears very blurry due to a loss in quality.

I resized the same image by inserting it in MS Word just to see if there would still be a loss in quality. Here, there was no noticeable loss in quality. I know that when you resize an image there is always some quality loss as there are a different number of pixels in the smaller image. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to do a similar thing to MS Word in Python where we shrink an image to a given size without a noticeable loss in quality.

I've tried to use different interpolation methods in PIL but they all result in a very noticeable loss in quality. I'd be very appreciative if someone could help me with figuring out a solution to this problem as all the approaches I've tried result in a very noticeable quality loss.

Comment: What tool did you use in PIL to resize the image?

Comment: How did you resize the image in Word??? You probably only changed it apparent size on the page, without affecting how many pixels the image has.

Comment: @pavel I used both PIL.thumbnail and PIL.resize with all the different interpolation options available for the resized

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did the resizing in Word by clicking on the image and then going to a corner and shrinking the image. Could you expand a bit on how you can change the size without affecting the number of pixels? My understanding (which could be wrong) is that there is a set pixel size on the displays. So if a pic shrinks, then how can you have the same number of pixels if the pixel size is the same?

Comment: 144x72 Is a really small portion of your screen. You’d have to zoom out the page very far to get your image to that number of pixels on the screen. The thing is, you don’t know how far you need to go. You don’t know how many pixels something is on the screen in your Word program. If it has more detail than what PIL resizing does, it has more pixels.

Comment: Ah ok. So you're saying that rather than the picture retaining its actual resolution, it only seems like it is doing so in Word. That helps. Thank you!